# How to overlap two components on a vaadin horizontal layout.

Tags: layout, groovy, vaadin, vaadin7

How can i overlap two components in a horizontal layout. I have a progress bar in which i am trying  to add a label upon it. The problem is i have structured my layout as horizontal layout upon a vertical layout. I have added components into the horizontal layout. As per my below code how can i add a two label upon a progress bar component, _process. This whole layout is build through Vaadin 7.6.3, Groovy programming.

The main layout is:

```
_VLayout = new VerticalLayout();
_VLayout.setSizeFull();
_VLayout.setSpacing(true);
_VLayout.addStyleName("new");
setCompositionRoot(_vLayout);
```

The layout added into vertical layout is horizontal layout which is _Layout.

```
_Layout = new HorizontalLayout();
_Layout.setSpacing(true);
_Layout.setSizeFull();
_Layout.addComponents(_machineName, _process, _Label, _time);
_Layout.setExpandRatio(_machineName, 0.1f);
_Layout.setExpandRatio(_process, 0.4f);
_Layout.setExpandRatio(_Label, 0.2f);
_Layout.setExpandRatio(_time, 0.3f);
```

I wanted to add a label on a **_process**, which is a progress bar. But how can i do that. ?any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: This is not possible with `HorizontalLayout` or `VerticalLayout`. You can try to use a `CSSLayout` or `AbsoluteLayout`, see [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/layout/layout-overview.html).

Comment: Thank you @SteffenHarbich, Can i use a absolut layout with a horizontal one, how can i achieve a label upon a progressbar. I wanted it because of less features of progress bar.

Comment: I don't know your use case for the progressbar but there are workarounds. You could, for example, use a HorizontalLayout (eg. width: 50px) as wrapper and add a progressbar and a label with width = 2 x wrapper width each (eg, 100px).

Comment: Thank you @JuliusHörger.